# How do I say Every/Each "Noun"

Tags: translation, expressions

So, the sentence I wanna build here is (talking about reading japanese books):

> Every/Each line you read, there are lots of new kanjis and words.

The only pattern I remember that is a bit similar to that is **すれば…するほど**, but I think that would end up changing the meaning to "The more lines you read, the more...".

So, with the research I did, the best I could come up with is:

> それぞれ一条を読むと、新しい漢字や言葉がたくさんある。

google actually recommends me to use 「すべての」 but I guess that's totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Every/Each line you read, there are lots of new kanjis and words.

I think the phrase you're looking for is ごとに(毎に).

「一行読む**ごとに**、新しい漢字や言葉がたくさん出てくる。」

Comment: ohh I remember seeing ごとに once, but none of my researches brought that up, thanks a lot!!